# MVC3 ValidationAttribute break

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validationattribute, asp.net-mvc-migration

I upgraded my project from MVC2 to MVC3 and all custom ValidationAttributes broke. At some point in the model binder phase, it throws this exception:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext.set_DisplayName(String value)
```

I can't figure out what changes... there is no DisplayName..

I suspect the IsValid override, which supposedly changed somehow, but the signature is the same.

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
   ....
}
```

MORE INFO:

It apparently affects "AttributeTargets.Class" properties, as in:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class MyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change AttributeTargets.Class to AttributeTargets.Property and to rewrite each validator to work with a given property.